# Find a harmonic function on two concentric balls?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

[image]

**My attempt:**

I thought about using Poisson Integral formula since the area is two concentric balls. Then I get something like the following:
$u(x)=\frac{1}{nw_nR}\int_{\partial B_R(p)}(\frac{R^2-x^2}{|y-x|^2}*b)dy$ on the big ball and $u(x)=\frac{1}{nw_nR}\int_{\partial B_R(p)}(\frac{R^2-x^2}{|y-x|^2}*a)dy$ on the small ball.

Then I got stuck. How to deal with the boundary condition at $u=a$, the Poisson Integral formula doesn't work well.

I totally have no clue about this problem. Can anyone give me some answers or clues?

Thanks so much about your help!! **:)**

Comment: The boundary values are rotationally symmetric, hence so will be $u$. Do you know a harmonic function $f(x) = g(\lvert x\rvert)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! I didn't know about that harmonic function:)

Comment: But now you know which one I mean?

Comment: @DanielFischer I still don't know now. Could you please give me some more clues? :)

Comment: Newton potentially knew what I was talking about ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Why the boundary values are rotationally symmetric, then so will bed $u$?

Comment: That follows from the uniqueness of the solution of the Dirichlet problem for such domains. If $\tilde{u}$ is $u$ rotated by something, then $u$ and $\tilde{u}$ are solutions of the same Dirichlet problem.

Comment: In case you didn't understand the hint: the functions are called Newton potentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on comments by Daniel Fischer:

> The boundary values are rotationally symmetric, hence so will be $u$

You don't actually need a proof of this statement (since your task is to find one solution, not all of them) so I would rather say:

> The boundary values are rotationally symmetric, hence we should look for a solution that is rotationally symmetric.

In the pool of rotationally symmetric harmonic functions we find constants and power $2-n$ of distance function (replaced with the logarithm of   distance function when $n=2$). You can also make linear combinations of these, since the PDE is linear. Try to fit a linear combination to the boundary conditions.